# displaying lowest starting from product price on opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Instead of having a base price on the product and displaying that I want to set the base price as 0.00 and display the lowest costing option price i.e

Polo shirt price = 0

Small = £10

Medium = £15

Large = £20

and it should display Starting from £10

Currently on the product page it displays price as 0 until and option is selected

```
<?php echo $price; ?>
```

I want it to do something like this but i am unsure of the syntax

```
<?php $min_value [] = $options['option_value']; ?>
<?php $min_value_price [] = $min_value['price']; ?>
<?php $min = min($min_value_price); ?>
<?php echo $min; ?>
```

Is this somewhere along the right lines? Currently it doesn't display anything with the above code

Model

```
public function getProductOptions($product_id) {
    $product_option_data = array();

    $product_option_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option po LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option` o ON (po.option_id = o.option_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_description od ON (o.option_id = od.option_id) WHERE po.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND od.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY o.sort_order");

    foreach ($product_option_query->rows as $product_option) {
        if ($product_option['type'] == 'select' || $product_option['type'] == 'radio' || $product_option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $product_option['type'] == 'image') {
            $product_option_value_data = array();

            $product_option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value ov ON (pov.option_value_id = ov.option_value_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description ovd ON (ov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id) WHERE pov.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pov.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['product_option_id'] . "' AND ovd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY ov.sort_order");

            foreach ($product_option_value_query->rows as $product_option_value) {
                $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                    'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                    'option_value_id'         => $product_option_value['option_value_id'],
                    'name'                    => $product_option_value['name'],
                    'image'                   => $product_option_value['image'],
                    'quantity'                => $product_option_value['quantity'],
                    'subtract'                => $product_option_value['subtract'],
                    'price'                   => $product_option_value['price'],
                    'price_prefix'            => $product_option_value['price_prefix'],
                    'weight'                  => $product_option_value['weight'],
                    'weight_prefix'           => $product_option_value['weight_prefix']
                );
            }

            $product_option_data[] = array(
                'product_option_id' => $product_option['product_option_id'],
                'option_id'         => $product_option['option_id'],
                'name'              => $product_option['name'],
                'type'              => $product_option['type'],
                'option_value'      => $product_option_value_data,
                'required'          => $product_option['required']
            );
        } else {
            $product_option_data[] = array(
                'product_option_id' => $product_option['product_option_id'],
                'option_id'         => $product_option['option_id'],
                'name'              => $product_option['name'],
                'type'              => $product_option['type'],
                'option_value'      => $product_option['option_value'],
                'required'          => $product_option['required']
            );              
        }
    }

    return $product_option_data;
}
```

Controller

```
$this->data['options'] = array();

        foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this-  >request->get['product_id']) as $option) { 
            if ($option['type'] == 'select' || $option['type'] == 'radio' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $option['type'] == 'image') { 
                $option_value_data = array();

                foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
                    if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                        if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                            $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                        } else {
                            $price = false;
                        }

                        $option_value_data[] = array(
                            'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                            'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                            'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                            'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                            'price'                   => $price,
                            'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                        );
                    }
                }

                $this->data['options'][] = array(
                    'product_option_id' => $option['product_option_id'],
                    'option_id'         => $option['option_id'],
                    'name'              => $option['name'],
                    'type'              => $option['type'],
                    'option_value'      => $option_value_data,
                    'required'          => $option['required']
                );                  
            } elseif ($option['type'] == 'text' || $option['type'] == 'textarea' || $option['type'] == 'file' || $option['type'] == 'date' || $option['type'] == 'datetime' || $option['type'] == 'time') {
                $this->data['options'][] = array(
                    'product_option_id' => $option['product_option_id'],
                    'option_id'         => $option['option_id'],
                    'name'              => $option['name'],
                    'type'              => $option['type'],
                    'option_value'      => $option['option_value'],
                    'required'          => $option['required']
                );                      
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do I show a query on here?

Comment: place your query fetching php code along with your question...

Comment: Will that be in the controller or the view file?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following code in controller *inside first loops if condition* Just after

`$option_value_data = array();` around line 349.

```
if($option['option_id'] == your_option_id){
  function cmp($a, $b)
  {
    return $b['price'] + $a['price'];
  }
  usort($option['option_value'], "cmp");
  $this->data['min_price'] = $option['option_value'][0]['price'];
}
```

Replace `your_option_id` with required option ID you want. 
Now in template file check if `$min_price` is set then echo `$min_price` else echo default price.

```
if(isset($min_price)){
echo $min_price;
......
}else{
echo $price
......
}
```

Comment: This sort of works but I need it to be specific to the product so would have to use ['product_id'] however when I have tried to put that into the if statement it doesn't work

Comment: you can pass product id if you want

if($option['option_id'] == 15 && $product_id==Your_Product_ID){

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the settings... Product should not have a price *$0.0* while options are setting the product's price. Instead of this the product should have some price (You can use the lowest possible for the product) and options then only modify this base price:

- T-shirt polo: $10.0

  - Small (S): +$0.0
  - Medium (M): +$1.0
  - Large (L): +$2.0
  - X-Large (XL): +$3.0
  - XX-Large (XXL): +$4.0

If Your store is selling products where options will always modify the price, You can then only check (in the template) whether the product has options, and in this case You can display something like *Price: starting from $10.0*, if the products has no options, display it like usual, e.g. *Price: $10.0*.

Or is there any big reason for setting the base price to *0.0*?

Just my very own opinion: people don't like (in general) when a T-shirt (or any other piece of clothes) has different price regarding the size they need and moreover they can be discouraged when their size is more expensive. It is a good practice to calculate some average price for a T-shirt (or any other piece of clothes) and use this average price for all sizes. If I had to do that, I would expect to sell e.g. 20% of S, 30% of M and L, 15% of XL and 5% of XXL - then I could calculate the average price as 0.2 x 10 + 0.3 x 11 + 0.3 x 12 + 0.15 x 13 + 0.05 x 14 = 2 + 3.3 + 3.6 + 1.95 + 0.7 = 11.55. I will then use this average price for all sizes of this very shirt...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace order  in mysql query (model file)

```
  $product_option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value ov ON (pov.option_value_id = ov.option_value_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description ovd ON (ov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id) WHERE pov.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pov.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['product_option_id'] . "' AND ovd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY ov.sort_order");
```

to

```
  $product_option_value_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value pov LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value ov ON (pov.option_value_id = ov.option_value_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description ovd ON (ov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id) WHERE pov.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pov.product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['product_option_id'] . "' AND ovd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY pov.price ASC");
```

**ov.sort_order** >>
**pov.price ASC**

or

**ov.sort_order** >>
**pov.price DESC**